# Find all possible interpretations of an array of digits

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Consider a coding system for alphabets to integers where ‘a’ is represented as 1, ‘b’ as 2, .. ‘z’ as 26. Given an array of digits (1 to 9) as input, write a function that prints all valid interpretations of input array.

```
/*Examples

Input: {1, 1}
Output: ("aa", 'k") 
[2 interpretations: aa(1, 1), k(11)]

Input: {1, 2, 1}
Output: ("aba", "au", "la") 
[3 interpretations: aba(1,2,1), au(1,21), la(12,1)]

Input: {9, 1, 8}
Output: {"iah", "ir"} 
[2 interpretations: iah(9,1,8), ir(9,18)]*/
```

My c code for this

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string.h>
int a[10]={2,3,4,4,2,4,2,8,9};
char c[]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

void func(int i,char result[10])
{
    if(i==10)
    {
       int l=strlen(result);
       for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
           cout<<result[j];
    }

    else
    {
        if(10*a[i]+a[i+1]<26)
        {
            strcat(result,"c[10*a[i]+a[i+1]]");
            func(i+2,result);
        }

        strcat(result,"c[a[i]]");
        func(i+1,result);
    }
}

int main()
{

    func(0,"");
}
```

I am not able to find out the errors. can you help me out??

Comment: What errors do you see?

Comment: "using namespace std" is hardly "your C code". I assume you meant C++?

Comment: Also, you are trying to strcat onto a string literal, which is both insufficiently short and read-only.

Comment: Vaughn Cato-- Its a run time error(segmentation fault)

Comment: H2CO3-- yes i meant c++ only

Comment: consider using `std::map<int, char> character_mapping;`

Comment: `"c[a[i]]"` doesn't do what you think it does. Use `std::string` and `result += c[a[i]];`, and only use C-style string manipulation when you want to make life difficult for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int a[9]={2,3,4,4,2,4,2,8,9};
char c[]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

void func(int i,char result[11])
{
    if(i==10)
    {
      printf ("%s\n", result);
    }
    else
    {
        char * temp = (char *)malloc(11);
        sprintf(temp, "%s%c", result, c[a[i] - 1]);
        func(i+1,temp);
        free(temp);

        if(i < 9 && 10*a[i]+a[i+1] < 26)
        {
            char * temp = (char *)malloc(11);
            sprintf(temp, "%s%c", result, c[10*a[i]+a[i+1] - 1]);
            func(i+2, temp);
            free (temp);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    func(0,"");
}
```

**Output**

```
bcddbdbhi
bcddxbhi
wddbdbhi
wddxbhi
```

**Potential fatal problems with your code**

1. `strcat(result,"c[10*a[i]+a[i+1]]");` and `strcat(result,"c[a[i]]");` you are concatenating those strings to `result` which is of size just 10, instead of concatenating the character corresponding to that number.

**Other problems**

1. Inside `if(10*a[i]+a[i+1]<26)` you are changing the contents of `result`, when the recursion is over, the value of result is not the same as what it was when it entered the function. So its better to create new strings inside and free them when their task is over.

**Suggestions**

1. Try not to mix C and C++ functions.

Answer (score 1):

One error that I see is that your result array may not have 10 characters.

```
for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
cout<<result[j];
```

This will result in segmentation fault.

EDIT: If you are open to using C++ elements, then I would prefer using a std::string instead of char array for result.

Answer (score 1):

You asked about errors. Here goes:

1. Do **not** put "using namespace" before other includes, this may result in really weird errors from compiler in other projects.
2. a[10] is not defined, but is evaluated on call func(9, result);
3. Also, call func(9, result) may lead to call func(9+2, result).
4. strcat(result,"c[10*a[i]+a[i+1]]"); adds string "c[10*a[i]+a[i+1]]" to result. I doubt this is the result you want. Also, compiler should recommend you to use strncat() instead.
5. It is better to use std::string and std::stringstream, unless you have some really good reason to avoid them.
6. Variable **a** is used in func(), but isn't passed as an argument. Generally, this is **not** a good idea.

Sample code (this uses a few other tricks):

```
    void PrintDecodings(const int* a, size_t length, std::string acc){
        static const char* alphabet = "0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        if(length == 0){
            std::cout << acc << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        if(length == 1){
            std::cout << acc << alphabet[*a] << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        if(10*a[0]+a[1] <= 26){ //At this point, length>=2, so a[1] is OK
            PrintDecodings(a+2, length-2, acc+alphabet[10*a[0]+a[1]]);
        }
        return PrintDecodings(a+1, length-1, acc+alphabet[*a]);
    }

    //...
        PrintDecodings(a, 9, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string.h>
int a[3]={1,2,1};
char c[]={'NULL','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

void func(int i,char result[3],int r)
{
    if(i==3)
    {
      for(int j=0;j<r;j++)
           cout<<result[j];
       cout<<"\n";
       return;
    }
    if(10*a[i]+a[i+1]<26)
    {
      result[r]=c[10*a[i]+a[i+1]];
      func(i+2,result,r+1);
    }
    result[r]=c[a[i]];
    func(i+1,result,r+1);

}


int main()
{
    char result[10];
    func(0,result,0);
}
```